# How do I get access to errors in custom Ktor JWT challenge?

Tags: kotlin, jwt, ktor

I'd like to be able to respond differently to different JWTAuth errors, so have customised the challenge (below is some code I've been using to test). Unfortunately the context is returning an empty list for the errors. I've tested with an expired token and with no token at all.

```
fun JWTAuthenticationProvider.Configuration.customConfigure() {
    verifier(verifier)
    realm = ISSUER
    challenge { _, _ ->
      call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, JSONObject(mapOf("err" to context.authentication.allErrors)))
    }
    validate { 
      if (it.payload.audience.contains(AUDIENCE)) {
        it.payload.getClaim("id").asString().let { id -> userDao.getUserById(id) }
      } else null
    }
  }
```

I was wondering if I was perhaps missing something. Hoping someone can help!

Comment: I don't know either. What I did was I manually checked what the error was, and sent that accordingly without the JWT config function.

Comment: @NeelKamath I wouldn't mind doing that either. Is there anywhere I can see how you did it? I was using `statuspages` but then all I could do was catch the error without a cause, so couldn't give different responses.

Comment: My code is rather contrived, and it's possible I've misunderstood your question. But what I've done is made my own auth function. I haven't created an extension method on `JWTAuthenticationProvider.Configuration`. The first line of every endpoint which requires auth calls this function, which `throw`s the relevant `Exception` if required.

Comment: @NeelKamath ah, I see. I have written my own auth in Node backends, so maybe I will do the same in Ktor. Thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the validate block, you can check the error by using the payload and respond by throwing an exception using Status Pages feature

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it does what I need it to do, so it's fine for now. I used the custom challenge to throw an exception with a specific error message depending on the error.

```
fun JWTAuthenticationProvider.Configuration.customConfigure() {
    verifier(verifier)
    realm = ISSUER
    challenge { _, _ ->
      // get custom error message if error exists
      val errorMessage = call.request.headers["Authorization"]?.let {
        if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
          try {
            val jwt = it.replace("Bearer ", "")
            verifier.verify(jwt)
            ""
          } catch (e: Exception) {
            when (e) {
              is JWTVerificationException ->
                if (e.localizedMessage.contains("expired")) "Token expired" else "Invalid token"
              else -> "Unknown token error"
            }
          }
        } else "Authorization token empty"
      } ?: "No authorization header"
      // if error throw UnauthorizedException
      if (errorMessage.isNotEmpty()) {
        throw UnauthorizedException(errorMessage)
      }
    }
    validate {
      if (it.payload.audience.contains(AUDIENCE)) {
        it.payload.getClaim("id").asString().let { id -> userDao.getUserById(id) }
      } else null
    }
  }
```

Then as suggested I have used the status pages feature to respond.

```
// catch authorization exception
exception<UnauthorizedException> {
      call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, JSONObject(mapOf("err" to it.message)))
    }
```

Comment: Would `verifier.verify()` be called twice in this solution? Once in Ktor's code, and once in this challenge function?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it would. I landed up no longer using Ktor's JWT Authentication because I could not fix this problem.

Comment: did you find any solution or any alternatives?

Comment: @KemalCengiz no I didn't, but I haven't tried in a very long time. I landed up re-writing parts of the Ktor Auth feature and integrating Firebase Auth to eventually get what I needed.

Comment: thanks. they should really improve auth in ktor..